# Prove that if an average of a thousand numbers is less than 7, then at least one of the numbers being averaged is less than 7

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I tried proving this by contraposition, by saying, "If every number that is being averaged is greater than 7, then the average of a thousand numbers is less than 7."  This seems easier to prove, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: The contrapositive would be, if all the numbers are greater than or equal to 7, then the average cannot be less than 7, if you want to prove that.

Answer (score 5):

You have $n$ numbers $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$.

If $x_i \ge 7$ for all $i$, then $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n \ge 7n$ and so $\dfrac{1}{n}(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n) \ge 7$.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine each number is $7+e_i$, with $e_i \ge 0$. If $1 \le i \le n$, we have n numbers, so the average is $7 + \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n e_i}{n}$, which, unless at least one of the $e_i$ is negative, is definitely greater than or equal to 7.