# Using contrapositive to Prove that if an average of a thousand numbers is less than 7, then at least one of the numbers being averaged is less than 7

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing

so I know that the contrapositive will be something like;

If all the numbers are greater than or equal to 7, then the average cannot be less than 7.

How do i go about proving it from there? or is there any other method of proving it? if so how?

I really appreciate the help from anybody!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144404/prove-that-if-an-average-of-a-thousand-numbers-is-less-than-7-then-at-least-one

Comment: Are the answers to that link proof by contrapositive? @turkeyhundt

Comment: @lhf's appears to be

Comment: Don't deface your question.

Answer (score 2):

`"if an average of a thousand numbers is less than 7, then at least one of the numbers being averaged is less than 7"`

is true if and only if the contrapositive is true, which is

`"if none of the numbers are less than 7, then the average of those numbers is not less than 7"`

To prove the contrapositive, suppose $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{1000}$ are the numbers to average, and that $x_i \ge 7$ for each $i$. Then $average = \sum_{i=1}^{1000} \frac{x_i}{1000} \ge \sum \frac{7}{1000} = 7$.

Comment: is there anyway to prove it without using the summations? @MarkG

Comment: @Erick Do you have a way to define "average" without summations?

Comment: @Erick, no, you must have the summations. To point of the exercise is to get you familiar with proofs and the idea of contrapositive, without getting bogged down on anything too technical. The average of $n$ numbers is just the sum of those numbers, divided by $n$.